# jQuery text shows limited and toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

my text content output from mysql, but we can just treat it as plain text for now. 
I'd like to limit my words to 120 words, then add toggle `show more` button.  I know toggle is easy to achieve, but I don't really know how to limit my words and insert show more toggle button automatically.

this is my code

```
<div id="paragrah">
    Donec vitae mollis leo. Quisque ut metus ac velit porttitor sollicitudin quis mattis purus. Quisque id risus id sem porta gravida eu nec neque. Praesent non odio nibh, vitae tincidunt sapien. Maecenas rutrum mollis mauris, eu condimentum nunc viverra nec. Donec fringilla imperdiet volutpat. Morbi in sem ante. Phasellus libero purus, viverra a aliquam ac, eleifend eu nisl. Etiam quis odio nec quam rhoncus iaculis ac quis velit. Sed ut lacus quis enim tempor ullamcorper. Donec odio ligula, porta et bibendum aliquam, blandit vitae lacus.
    <div class="myimage">picture</div>
    <div class="myimage">picture</div>
    <div class="myimage">picture</div>
</div>
```

Also I attached an image to explain what I am expecting to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
function excerpt(str, nwords) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  words.splice(nwords, words.length - 1);
  return words.join(' ') + '&hellip;';
}
```

Then cache your original contents with `data` and create a button to toggle between `data` and `excerpt` based on the text, either "show" or "hide".

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/QLYey/

Comment: Maybe you should not overwrite `excerpt` in your fiddle: `var excerpt = excerpt($div.text(), 120);`

Answer (score 2):

Why do you care about the number of words?  The area that a given number of words takes up can vary GREATLY depending on the length of the words.  The best approach would be probably to treat this with CSS/javascript.

Make the div a fixed height and provide it with a text-overflow setting (you can define your custom string for the overflow).  Then with javascript expansion, you can just and a class that overrides the fixed height and text-overflow, to give you the full content.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would handle the formatting of the "teaser" text on the server side where you can use whatever language you want to create the HTML. Then the client can run JavaScript to expand the content which is already present hidden in the page. A complete example is linked at the bottom at jsfiddle with multiple expandable sections.

The expanding code using jQuery:

```
$('.show-more').click(function(event) {
    $(event.target)
        .closest('.expando')
            .find('.three-dots')
                .remove()
                .end()
            .find('.rest')
                .show()
                .end()
            .end()
        .detach();
});​
```

Working example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wJMh9/3/

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
var text=$("#paragrah").html().substring(1,200)​;
$("#paragrah").html(text + '...' );​​​​
```